# Register a poolboy pool in registry

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

Is it possible to register a `:poolboy` pool in registry (`:gproc` or `Registry` in elixir 1.4) after it was started?

I need to implement some kind on pub/sub architecture on pools. And I'd like to register multiple pools under the same alias.

`Registry` has `:duplicate`, and `:gproc` has `:p`, but it looks like none of them works with `:via` tuples, so I can't use it in `name` of my pool.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `Registry` only allows registering the *current* process under a given name.

So to use registry, you'd need to start a process to act as a proxy to each Poolboy pool, eg a `GenServer` module `PoolProxy`.

```
defmodule PoolProxy do
  use GenServer

  def init(poolname) do
    {:ok, _} = Registry.register(Registry.PoolPubSub, "PoolPubSub", nil)
    {:ok, poolname}
  end

  def handle_call(:notify_pool, _from, poolname) do
    # interact with poolboy pool here...
  end
end
```

Once registered, you can then pub-sub to the proxy processes, with

```
Registry.dispatch(Registry.PoolPubSub, "PoolPubSub", fn entries ->
  for {pid, _} <- entries, do: GenServer.call(pid, :notify_pool)
end)
```